# let's encrypt AWS redhat

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm setup a server for testing in AWS EC2 and I can't secure the default domain.

I'm following this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html

I've install:

- Apache
- SSL

now I'm trying to secure with Let's encrypt the default domain and use it for testing.

I'm using this specific instructions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html#letsencrypt

I've also tried this ones:

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centosrhel7-apache

It seems that I manage to install the Epel repo as you can see from the screenshot but I cannot install certbot

[repos list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVUiM.png)

it gave me an error about python, it seems that I need python 2.6 instead of Python 2.7.

[python errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfV9l.png)

How can I install let's encrypt and secure the default domain?

Comment: Get rid of the mistakenly installed EPEL 6 repo.

Comment: how can I do that? and which instruction I should follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I used this instructions to install let's encrypt as I cannot solve the problem with Epel and the dependencies.

https://www.tecmint.com/install-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-to-secure-apache-on-rhel-centos/

I don't test the auto renew as this server will be shut down in less than a month but the SSL is issued correctly and, thanks to @fugolmere to let me know about LE and the default domain (I used a free domain that we don't use at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

> "How can I install let's encrypt and secure the default domain?"

If by "default domain" you mean the *Public DNS* created for the EC2 instance, for example:

**ec2-10.10.10.10.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com**

Then I don't believe you can use Let's Encrypt to issue certs for this domain.

It appears *amazonaws.com* TLD is blacklisted due to the ephemeral nature of EC2. In other words, Let's Encrypt can issue you a cert for your instance's subdomain which you own today, but tomorrow it might be owned by somebody else. I assume this is incongruent with the identity aspect of CA certs.

To use Let's Encrypt with EC2 you will need to register a domain and create an DNS A record in your domain host which points to your EC2 instance's *IPv4 Public IP*.

Ref:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/policy-forbids-issuing-for-name-on-amazon-ec2-domain/12692

Comment: yes, i was meant to use that domain for testing. OK i will need to check if we have a free domain that we own but we don't use at the moment in our DNS registar. Thank you